# Implement hooks for js class attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The title may be confusing, because of how the community thinks of "Classes" as interchangeable of "React Class components".

**But no, I'm talking about pure, JavaScript classes,** where a hook written in one which checks if its properties changed, and it could be used in a react-hook component.

I have this class

```
class DatabaseRecords {
    private _ loading: boolean
    private _records: string[][]
}
```

Could I write a hook for this class, so it can be used by a react-hook?

Like, everytime `_loading` updates, to also update the hook.

eg.

```
class DatabaseRecords {
    private _ loading: boolean
    private _records: string[][]

    useIsLoading() {
        // I wanna be a hook :<
        return this._loading
    }
}

const RenderRecords = (props) => {
    const isLoading = DatabaseRecords.useIsLoading()
    if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>

    // [...]
}
```

I'm really not sure if react-hooks were ever supposed to work on this basis and if I'm being stupid and missing something obvious.
Or maybe, if there's a better way to approach this issue.

Comment: The part that's missing is the concept of state and the awareness of changes which is unique to React and not present in vanilla JS.  I see what you are trying to do here, which is to *respond to changes* in the `isLoading` property, but that's not going to happen with the way it is written now.  I don't know if it's technically possible, but even if it is, it would be a lot more straightforward to just rewrite the `DatabaseRecords` class into a `useDatabaseRecords` hook which uses `setState` internally.

Comment: Makes much sense, could imagine it going that way. The issue is that, sometimes you just need classes to model things in an OOP way as it sometimes is a cleaner way to architect your codebase, like `database.Add(record)`, so it would be an additional comfort if hooks could work with that use-case. But yeah, I do not see it going that way :P

Comment: You can write a hook such that the hook returns an object `database` with the method `add(record)`.  In fact I think we could have the hook return a class?  That part I might have to play with.

Comment: You can also have a hook that internally stores an instance of the class.  If we make certain class methods return a callback or even return a promise, we could use that to keep the state in sync.  Like `classInstance.fetchRecords.then( setIsLoading(false) )`. Do you have a fuller example class that I can play with?

Comment: Sure, I just made one, so I can test it out as well. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-platform-iyhmo Seems like a fun use-case to test nonetheless

Comment: The thing I was talking about with callbacks [didn't work](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64519659-4v1yz?file=/src/DidntWork.tsx), or at least I couldn't make it work.  Switched it to a working hook that's mush simpler not using classes.  But I'm still pondering this one because it is a very interesting question.

Comment: "Unique to React"... not so. Wasn't even the first framework implementing it.

Comment: @luixal I dont think we're making an argument here about whether React was the first to implement it. You're going off-topic, but thank you for your contribution nonetheless.